# Cannot read properties of undefined classes.root when put mergeProps to connect

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I tried add merge props to connect

```
export default compose(
withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true }),
 connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps,
    mergeProps
  )(MyComponent)
```

But it throw **TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'root')**
when i use connect without **mergeProps**, it works fine

Answer (score 0):

You need to show the actual functions for each of those parameters. Look into https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#connect-parameters As you can see those parameters are functions. Maybe it will help showing your functions?

Comment: Thanks. Problem was in props, mergeProps should return ownProps also, because this function do re-render component